# three.js - How to make animated cylinder net?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I need to animate conversion from simple cylinder to its net. Actually it should look like
[as pictured](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-KSm_otIxaW0/T06RUhG0klI/AAAAAAAAI4w/DzBDfDnJfMQ/s1600/razvertka_cilindra.gif). But I have no idea, how to make a lateral surface of the cylinder to turn into a rectangle, if this even possible.

Answer (score 0):

I advise using some 3d editor as Blender.

however you can use this: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets

Regards.